# 'livedvd' should be a synonym for 'live-cd'

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

[livedvd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/livedvd):

> a CD or DVD containing a bootable computer operating system.

[live-cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/live-cd):

> Questions related to live CDs, which allow you to test drive Ubuntu without installing it.

I'd suggest to have those two become synonyms.

Comment: [tag:livedvd] should also be synonymized to [tag:live-cd] since they're the same thing whether it's a DVD or a CD.